# Get HTTPS response

Tags: ruby, http, https

This works great:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json')
args = {include_entities: 0, include_rts: 0, screen_name: 'johndoe', count: 2, trim_user: 1}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(args)
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts resp.body
```

But changing from `http` to `https` leads to a meaningless error. I'm not asking why the error is meaningless, I would just like to know what's the closest means of doing `get_response` for `https`?

I've seen the 'HTTPS' example in the [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) doc but it looks not very impressive and will make me manually compose the URL from my parameters hash - no good.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a example which works for me under Ruby 1.9.3

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI.parse("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json")
args = {include_entities: 0, include_rts: 0, screen_name: 'johndoe', count: 2, trim_user: 1}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(args)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
response.body
```

Comment: the doc at my link says _In previous versions of ruby you would need to require ‘net/https’ to use HTTPS. This is no longer true._ - should we just ignore this?

Comment: you are right, require "net/http" is ok, i will edit the answer

Comment: the doc also says _require 'net/http' will also require ‘uri’ so you don’t need to require it separately._

Comment: You probably **don't** want the `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` from the example. Why use SSL if you DON'T verify the certificate? See http://jamesgolick.com/2011/2/15/verify-none..html.