# Doing HTTPS GET calls from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rest, http, ssl, https

Here is the code I am trying to run, censored for company security:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('https://<<the gitlab address>>')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
#http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
response.body
response.status
```

Here is even a snippet of code I got from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669152/get-https-response)

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI.parse("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json")
args = {include_entities: 0, include_rts: 0, screen_name: 'johndoe', count: 2, trim_user: 1}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(args)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
response.body
```

In both cases I am getting the same error at runtime:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=
1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (Open
SSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
        from findMonitorId.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I am confused as of where to go now, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is a failure to validate the cert. see: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: That seems to be an issue to solve it on OS X only, and I am on a Windows machine. @Mircea